# Google Charts json data not loading

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and Google Charts to try and generate a simple line graph with two data records.  I'm pulling the data successfully from the database, but the data isn't appearing on my chart.  The data consists of two records with two fields: `WeekOfEntry`(DateTime) and `Weight` (decimal). The chart appears, but the data points aren't there.  I'm guessing my data is formatted improperly?

Here's my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Load the Visualization API library and the linechart library.
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });

    //Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawLoseATonLineChart);

    //Callback that creates and populates a data table, instantiates the line chart,
    //passes in the data, and draws it.
    function drawLoseATonLineChart() {

        var url = "@Url.Action("GetChartStatistics")";

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: false
        }).responseText;

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'WeekOfEntry');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data.addRow([jsonData[i].WeekOfEntry, jsonData[i].Weight]);
        }

        var options = {
            title: 'Weight Progression',
            legend: {
                position: 'right',
                alignment: 'center'
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: 'Weight'
            },
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Week',
                slantedText: true,
                slantedTextAngle: 45

            },
            colors: ['E81A00']
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('lose-a-ton-line-chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Here's part of my `GetChartStatistics()` method:

```
var lineChartData = (from a in db.Associates
            join aw in db.AssociateWeights
                on a.RegistrationId equals aw.RegistrationId
            where a.EventId == eventId &&
                  a.Username == currentuser
            select new LineChartData
            {
                Weight = aw.Weight,
                WeekOfEntry = aw.WeekOfEntry
            });

return Json(lineChartData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Edit: Here's how my JSON data is formatted when it gets returned:

`"[{"Weight":190.0,"WeekOfEntry":"\/Date(1431921600000)\/"},{"Weight":121.0,"WeekOfEntry":"\/Date(1432526400000)\/"}]"`

Any ideas on why the data isn't loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you had an issue in your for loop. here is your modified code.

```
//Load the Visualization API library and the linechart library.
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });

    //Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawLoseATonLineChart);

var url = "@Url.Action("GetChartStatistics")";

var result = $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    async: false
});
var jsonData = result.responseText;
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'WeekOfEntry');
data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');

$.each(JSON.parse(jsonData), function (index, obj) {
    data.addRow([obj.WeekOfEntry, obj.Weight]);
});

var options = {
    title: 'Weight Progression',
    legend: {
        position: 'right',
        alignment: 'center'
    },
    vAxis: {
        title: 'Weight'
    },
    hAxis: {
        title: 'Week',
        slantedText: true,
        slantedTextAngle: 45

    },
    colors: ['E81A00']
};

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

chart.draw(data, options);


public JsonResult GetChartStatistics()
    {
        var lineChartData = new List<LineChartData>() { 
            new LineChartData() { WeekOfEntry = "sat", Weight = 1},
            new LineChartData() { WeekOfEntry = "sat1", Weight = 2},
            new LineChartData() { WeekOfEntry = "sat2", Weight = 3},
            new LineChartData() { WeekOfEntry = "sat3", Weight = 4},
        };

        return Json(lineChartData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your example, you probably want to iterate `jsonData` object, so replace the line:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
```

with

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++)
```

In addition since [data parameter supports date type](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam) you could consider to render `Week` as a date instead of Json string.

**Example**

```js
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawLoseATonLineChart);

function drawLoseATonLineChart() {

    var jsonData = [
        { "Weight": 190.0, "WeekOfEntry": "\/Date(1431921600000)\/" },
        { "Weight": 121.0, "WeekOfEntry": "\/Date(1432526400000)\/" }
    ];


    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'WeekOfEntry');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');

    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        var weekOfEntry = new Date(parseInt(jsonData[i].WeekOfEntry.substr(6,13)));
        data.addRow([weekOfEntry, jsonData[i].Weight]);
    }

    var options = {
        title: 'Weight Progression',
        legend: {
            position: 'right',
            alignment: 'center'
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Weight'
        },
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Week',
            slantedText: true,
            slantedTextAngle: 45

        },
        colors: ['E81A00']
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('lose-a-ton-line-chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={ 'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
<div id="lose-a-ton-line-chart" style="width: 640px; height: 480px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping through your JSON data, have you tried the arrayToDataTable function?

```
var dataTableData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(jsonData));
```

Comment: I tried this and I received an error that "First row is not an array."